# Como guardar ou reservar uma lista de objetos? (R)

Tags: r, lista

Em R, estou querendo "guardar uma lista de matrizes".

Na verdade, estou querendo reservar uma lista de 10 objetos, onde cada objeto vai virar uma matriz, depois de usar um for()

Algo tipo assim:

```
Data <- uma base de dados

Lista <- é a lista que eu quero guardar ou reservar (criar?)

for(i in 1:10)
{

 Lista[i]<- subset(Data, coluna1 == levels(Coluna1)[i] )

}
```

Dessa maneira, Lista é uma lista de 10 matrizes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, você pode tanto guardar matrizes em uma lista ou em um array.

Com o array a ideia seria usar um array de três dimensões. A terceira dimensão seria um indexador das matrizes. Entretanto, para esta solução, todas as matrizes tem que ter tamanho igual.

Por exemplo, o comando abaixo gera um array que pode ser interpretado como o seguinte: ele guarda 10 matrizes 2 x 2.

```
matrizes <- array(dim= c(2,2,10))
```

Depois você pode popular esse array indexando na terceira dimensão:

```
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:10){
  matrizes[,,i] <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol=2)
}
```

Assim, para acessar a primeira matriz:

```
matrizes[,,1]
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8356286
[2,]  0.1836433  1.5952808
```

ou a décima matriz

```
matrizes[,,10]

           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -0.3942900 1.1000254
[2,] -0.0593134 0.7631757
```

A outra opção é como você mesmo disse, armazenar em uma lista. Listas são bem flexíveis no R, então se  você quer guardar outros objetos juntos com as matrizes, ou se as matrizes forem de tamanhos diferentes, a lista é mais adequada.

```
matrizes <- list()

set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:10){
  matrizes[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol=2)
}
```

Acessando a matriz 1:

```
matrizes[[1]]
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8356286
[2,]  0.1836433  1.5952808
```

E a matriz 10:

```
matrizes[[10]]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -0.3942900 1.1000254
[2,] -0.0593134 0.7631757
```

Comment: No caso, como você pode ver no meu código, eu não tenho como determinar as dimensões das matrizes... elas vão se gerando dentro do comando for().. A ideia é que eu reserve uma lista com 10 matrizes genéricas e depois substituir cada uma delas por uma matriz de uma dimensão aleatória... eu até poderia criar uma lista com as 10 matrizes de 4x2 e depois tentar substituir, mas dá 10 erros: In ucs_educ_niveis[i] <- subset(inf_ucs_com_criancas_em_escola_2,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @Vasco se as matrizes forem de tamanhos diferentes então tem que ser por lista mesmo, é só você rodar o loop como eu coloquei no exemplo, substituindo o `matrix(rnorm(4), ncol=2)` pelo seu comando.

Comment: Entendi... Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Vasco se eu não estou errado você tem uma típica tarefa em que a solução mais elegante é um split. A solução que vou te apresentar é para quando você quer separar um conjunto de dados em relação aos níveis de um fator. Para exemplificar vou utilizar o conjunto de dados iris:

```
## Carregando os dados
data(iris)

## Vendo as primeiras linhas
head(iris)
```

Veja que a última coluna é a espécie. Vamos ver quantas espécies existem

```
## Mostrando os níveis de Species
levels(iris$Species)
```

Veja que existem três: [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"

Agora vou separar o data.frame em três, criando uma lista, onde cada elemento da lista é um data.frame contendo somente as linhas relativas ao nível do fator especificado no split.

```
## Separando por espécie
lista <- split(x = iris, f = iris$Species)
```

Pronto! Agora eu posso aplicar qualquer método nas partes separadas. Suponhamos que eu queira calcular a média da variável Sepal.Length para cada espécie:

```
## Média por espécie
lapply(lista, function(x) mean(x$Sepal.Length))

$setosa
[1] 5.006

$versicolor
[1] 5.936

$virginica
[1] 6.588
```

Se for uma função simples como a média, considerando apenas um fator, existe um jeito muito mais rápido com o tapply:

```
## Média por espécie
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)

     setosa versicolor  virginica 
     5.006      5.936      6.588
```

Mas observe que a solução com split é mais geral e vale para situações mais complexas que envolvem operações com mais de uma coluna.